# Good battery charger for AA+AAA batteries, especially for older batteries that don't charge well in other chargers

Tags: battery-life, battery

I currently have a cheap budget AA & AAA charger which can only charge batteries in pairs of two, and which does not do a good job on older batteries.

I'm looking for a good quality charger with these features:

- can charge batteries individually, not just in pairs of 2
- can 'revive' older batteries so to speak, or charge batteries which don't charge well anymore in other chargers
- doesn't require manual finetuning, I don't want to be hassling with voltage or amperage myself, it should preferably 'smart' charge any battery automatically

Especially that 2nd point seemed contradictory to me, but I've read several reviews and user experiences where this really makes a difference amongst chargers.

I've heard some good things about the Ansmann Powerline 4 Light and the Opus BT C3100. And several others come out well in different reviews too.

Any hints, tips, suggestions, personal experiences?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Powerex MH-C9000 WizardOne (by Maha?), that has served me VERY well for several years. It was probably one of the most pricy chargers available when I bought it, but I don't think the ones you mentioned were available back then.

Unfortunately It is discontinued, but still available from many stockists as at May 2021. The new version "Powerex MH-C9000PRO" is very similar, just doesn't have the Cycle Mode, (frankly not a big issue as I only ever got a few percent increase in capacity using it. If you really want to emulate the process, just do a Refresh 2 or 3 times or more.) and the Car adapter is an optional extra instead of being included.

Charges 1-4 AA or AAA NiMH or NiCD batteries via 4 independent slots. Can "Revive" batteries. Will charge any compatible battery automatically without intervention, but has 4 other modes if necessary (I.e. You need to decide when to do a Refresh or Break-In, it does the rest, or you can tinker with Charge and Discharge rates if you want to)

As it reports the actual full charge capacity, you can easily decide when to do a refresh if you make a few notes over the weeks and months.

All Modes: Charge Mode, Discharge Only mode, Refresh and Analyze Mode, Break-in Mode and Cycle Mode.

Mainly used on Eneloop and Eneloop Pro batteries. It has done quite notable recoveries on batteries that other chargers have "messed up", something like 30% capacity back up to 80%, just don't expect miracle recoveries on batteries exclusively charged by the Powerex... they seem to slowly decay with age over the years down to 80% or so and then die entirely.

mahaenergy.com have several other models too.